# Robot Graphical Representation in Real Time

Tags: control, robotic-arm, c++, manipulator, c

I'm working with a robot intended to be placed in a tele-echography environment. To control the robot I'm using a 6D space mouse that control each degree of freedom of the robot. However, since the rotation is made in the end effector, the end user would have difficulties in understanding where to move the mouse in order to do the desired motion, since the end effector's reference is constantly changing.

So, I'm thinking of doing a graphical representation of the motion of the robot in real time while the user controls the robot. The robot comes andith many API's to control it and to get sensor data. I'm currently using Qt Creator (C/C++) in order to send the mouse's commands to the robot, so I would like to integrate in my program some kind of simulator. What do you recommend as a C++ package / program in order to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: How about OpenGL? You really need a very basic representation of the robot, so a few triangles per link, and some lines to draw the coordinate systems in should do. You could get artistic and try to model the robot more precisely, but that's just bonus.

Comment: I've used **rviz** a number of times for this. It's great but your robot will have to interface with ROS (low hanging fruit for you)

Comment: @Shahbaz , Yes, I've looked into that. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @Jacksonkr Yeah, I'm not really knowledgeable with ROS but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using Qt, then Q3 3D would be an obviuos choice for 3D representations. Gaming engines like Unity (C#/JavaScript) or the Unreal Engine (C++) are also a suitable choice for representing robots in 3D. You will find plenty of exmples like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DqRkLQ5Sv8).

Using directly OpenGL is also an option, but if you want anything else then just simple 3D rerpesentations, probably a gaming engine would be a better option.